# Append unit to a XML column value in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have a table with a XML column for storing the file details. Now I want to update the size node in the XML column with KB or MB according to the value.

Sample data:

```
<FileInfo>
    <Field Name="Filename">PV_1_PV_4126_C-482N-25457-005_V1.pdf</Field>
    <Field Name="Created">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Modified">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded By">2120</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded On">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Size">755</Field>
</FileInfo>
```

Expected result:

```
<FileInfo>
    <Field Name="Filename">PV_1_PV_4126_C-482N-25457-005_V1.pdf</Field>
    <Field Name="Created">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Modified">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded By">2120</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded On">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Size">755 KB</Field>
</FileInfo>
```

Sample data:

```
<FileInfo>
    <Field Name="Filename">PV_1_PV_4126_C-482N-25457-005_V1.pdf</Field>
    <Field Name="Created">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Modified">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded By">2120</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded On">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Size">1024</Field>
</FileInfo>
```

Expected result:

```
<FileInfo>
    <Field Name="Filename">PV_1_PV_4126_C-482N-25457-005_V1.pdf</Field>
    <Field Name="Created">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Modified">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded By">2120</Field>
    <Field Name="Uploaded On">02/21/2017</Field>
    <Field Name="Size">1 MB</Field>
</FileInfo>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an *updateable CTE*

```
DECLARE @dummy TABLE(YourXMLColumn XML);
INSERT INTO @dummy VALUES
(
    N'<FileInfo>
        <!--More fields-->
        <Field Name="Size">755</Field>
    </FileInfo> '
)
,(
    N'<FileInfo>
        <!--More fields-->
        <Field Name="Size">1024</Field>
    </FileInfo> '
);

WITH ReplaceValue AS
(
    SELECT YourXMLColumn
          ,ca2.newSize
    FROM @dummy AS d
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT d.YourXMLColumn.value(N'(/FileInfo/Field[@Name="Size"]/text())[1]',N'int')) AS ca1(size)
    CROSS APPLY(SELECT CASE WHEN ca1.size % 1024=0 
                            THEN CAST(ca1.size/1024 AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' MB' 
                            ELSE CAST(ca1.size AS VARCHAR(10)) + ' KB' END) AS ca2(newSize)
)
UPDATE ReplaceValue SET YourXMLColumn.modify(N'replace value of (/FileInfo/Field[@Name="Size"]/text())[1] with sql:column("newSize")');

SELECT * FROM @dummy;
```

First I read the value of the "Size" field. If it is divideable by 1024 it will be written as "MB", otherwise the value remains as "KB".

The final `UPDATE` will update the CTE, but this affects the tables column actually. The `SELECT` shows the modified table data.